# IOS Simulator user interaction not working?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, hybrid

My Xcode ios Simulator lost the user interaction completely. Even the hardware buttons like Lock button, volume button itself not working. My app is open in simulator but i dont interact with it. I have tried a lot of solutions even i removed the Xcode & Simulators completely. But it doesn't work. Please help already i wasted a week for this week.

Comment: Have you tested same in real device?

Comment: yeah its working in real device. But emulator is not responding for any other app also. My emulator lost the user interaction completely.

Answer (score -4):

You can not access some component in simulator . Please try to access with real device. Also run the project into a real device for the solutions.

Comment: It's true that some functionalities are not available on simulator, but the basic functionalities, like what in this question has been mentioned, should be there.

Comment: I tried the home button, lock button that is also not working. It has to be lost the user interaction completely, i can't click, scroll anything to the emulator. Its just showing only, act as a view only type.